# Lists["User Information List"] is null

Tags: powershell, user-information-list

I'm trying to export groups from my site and I used this [script](http://kesarlajayasankar.blogspot.si/2014/03/export-sharepoint-group-to-excel-using.html#!/2014/03/export-sharepoint-group-to-excel-using.html).

```
$siteUrl="http://mysite"
$groupName="BWS Team"
$Output = @("GroupName|Name|Login|Email|Department|Title")
$web = Get-SPWeb $siteUrl
$site = $web.Site
$rootWeb = $site.RootWeb
$UserList = $rootWeb.Lists["User Information List"]
$web.SiteGroups[$groupName].Users|%{$user = $UserList.GetItemById($_.ID)
if($user -ne $null)
{
$JobTitle = $user["JobTitle"]
$Department = $user["Department"]
}
$Output += ($groupName+"|"+$_.Name+"|"+$_.UserLogin+"|"+$_.Email+"|"+$Department +"|"+$JobTitle)
}
$rootWeb.Dispose()
$web.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()
$Output > "D:\MembersExport.csv"



You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:8 char:37
+ $web.SiteGroups[$groupName].Users|%{$user = $UserList.GetItemById($_.ID)
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: Can you try replacing the % with ForEach ($user in $UserList)?

Comment: replaced $rootWeb.Lists["User Information List"] with $UserList = $rootWeb.SiteUserInfoList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the UserInformationList you need to directly call for it instead of using `<SPWeb>.Lists[<listTitle>]` like:

```
$siteUrl="http://mysite"
$web = Get-SPWeb $siteUrl
$userList = $web.SiteUserInfoList;
```

Comment: It is SiteUserInfoList, found thanks to intellisense in ISE

Comment: @malibeg oh right, changed it in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I ran the same script and it works well. if `$UserList` is null, that may mean the Title of the User Information List may have been modified. You can confirm that by browsing this Url: `http://yoursite/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx`. Alternatively, as suggested by @garglblarg, you can use `SPWeb.SiteUserInfoList` directly.

[SPWeb.SiteUserInfoList property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.siteuserinfolist.aspx)

Comment: thanks, what was the title of the list? Was it modified?